# How to estimate how much mason mix I need for a wall?

Tags: masonry, cinderblock

I am building a wall using Quikrete Mason Mix Type S 60 lb (as I think that is the correct product for gluing bricks together to form a wall). The wall will in total have use 400 cinder blocks, measuring 8x8x16", then kind with large holes in the middle. How do I make an estimate of how many bags of this mix I will need to secure the cinder blocks together?

Comment: How tall is this wall? How long is the wall before it turns 90 degrees or so? Will there be anything resting on it, like a roof structure? Will the wall sit on a concrete footing?

Comment: [inchcalculator.com](https://www.inchcalculator.com/block-mortar-calculator/) says you need forty-five 60lb bags, which sounds like enough to fill the blocks. - I'ma say eight. Then you go to the store and get 4 more. Then you go get 8 more. Then you take 4 back to the store. So, somewhere between 8 and 16 ;)